# Google Speech - not working from corporate firewall

Tags: java, google-speech-api

I am trying google speech API and I have taken java sample for google speech api from

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/tree/master/speech/cloud-client

This works fine when I try it from my home network. But the same code doesn't work when I try it from my office. it waits for 3 minutes and then throws the following exception. I am using 'asynchrecognize' mode.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.google.api.gax.grpc.ApiException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: DEADLINE_EXCEEDED
            at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:476)
            at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:455)
            at com.google.api.gax.grpc.OperationFuture$DataGetterRunnable.callImpl(OperationFuture.java:171)
            at com.google.api.gax.grpc.OperationFuture$DataGetterRunnable.call(OperationFuture.java:161)
            at com.google.api.gax.grpc.OperationFuture$DataGetterRunnable.call(OperationFuture.java:131)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
            at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
            at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.google.api.gax.grpc.ApiException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: DEADLINE_EXCEEDED
            at com.google.api.gax.grpc.ExceptionTransformingCallable$ExceptionTransformingFuture.onFailure(ExceptionTransformingCallable.java:108)
            at com.google.api.core.ApiFutures$1.onFailure(ApiFutures.java:53)
            at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$6.run(Futures.java:1764)
            at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$DirectExecutor.execute(MoreExecutors.java:456)
            at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.executeListener(AbstractFuture.java:817)
            at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.complete(AbstractFuture.java:753)
            at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.setException(AbstractFuture.java:634)
            at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$GrpcFuture.setException(ClientCalls.java:463)
            at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$UnaryStreamToFuture.onClose(ClientCalls.java:439)
            at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.closeObserver(ClientCallImpl.java:428)
            at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.access$100(ClientCallImpl.java:76)
            at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.close(ClientCallImpl.java:514)
            at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.access$700(ClientCallImpl.java:431)
            at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:546)
            at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:52)
            at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor$TaskRunner.run(SerializingExecutor.java:152)
            at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
            ... 6 more
```

I suspect that there is a network permission issue and I need to open some port but not sure which one?